# Transfer specified number of bytes from one stringstream to another

Tags: c++, stringstream

Given

- a `size_t n` (typically valued in the millions)
- a `stringstream a`, containing many more than `n` bytes
- a pre-existing empty `stringstream b`

what might be a good way to transfer `n` bytes from `a` to `b`?

I think the following would work

```
std::string s;
s.resize(n);
a.read(&s[0], n);
b << s.rdbuf();
```

but isn't there a way to skip that intermediate string `s` and transfer the `n` bytes directly from `a` to `b`?

Comment: I would think a combination of sputc and sbumpc on the respective rdbufs over an iteration loop would do what you are trying. I'm not aware of anyway to simply do a N-element transfer in one shot, however.

Comment: std::copy, std::{i,o}streambuf_iterator

Comment: @n.m. there you go. duh. don't know why I didn't think of that. proper streambuf iterators and [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) would certainly seem to fit the bill.